# How to Store Time in Ruby/Rails other than local or utc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I have a unique situation. We are running a hosted application with a different Rails environment for each customer so I don't maintain multiple copies of the code base. Each customer is in a different time zone and I have to store the time in that timezone for our desktop application to work properly. I can't change the system time to match since there are multiple instances running on the same server. My question is I know I can do this:

```
config.active_record.default_time_zone = :utc
```

or this:

```
config.active_record.default_time_zone - :local
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

```
config.active_record.default_time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```

and still have the system clock be Central Time?

BTW we are using SQL Server and JRuby

Answer (score 0):

You should store time in database in UTC format, also keep each users timezone settings in the database.

Keep in mind, that SQL server can have its own timezone settings, so you should configure it properly too.

Comment: In this case I simply cannot do this. I do not have control of the database and it would take a significant amount of time four developers to back port that code to support UTC. We may be able to do this in the future, but not at this point.

Comment: I am just add the offset to the date (so it gets subtracted and the time is correct). I don't like this solution (it feels hackish), if anyone else has a solution, I would welcome it. To give Stanislav credit, he solution above would work in an ideal world but doesn't in my situation.